# Is this a bug of ListLogPlot? (Bug introduced in v12.1 and continuing)

Tags: plotting, bugs

**This bug has been fixed in version 13.0**

---

Using `ListLogPlot[Range[10000], Axes -> True, Frame -> True]`, only the left frame has a log scale tick, the right frame still has a linear scale tick.

Comment: The `bugs` tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.

Comment: Is the problem solved if you add the `FrameTicks -> True` option?

Comment: This is by design.  Only "y" axis gets tickes according to scale used. For example `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]` you will see the same. Use FraneTicks as suggested above.

Comment: I can reproduce this starting with Mathematica 12.1. In earlier versions, the right frame also has logarithmic ticks, as one would expect. Please report this issue too Wolfram support

Comment: The `FrameTicks` are correct if you use `ListLogLogPlot[ Range[10000], Axes -> True, Frame -> True]`

Comment: @Nasser I can't agree with you on this, as @Bob Hanlon has pointed out, using `ListLogLogPlot[ Range[10000], Axes -> True, Frame -> True]` the right frame is also in the log scale. So it is not by design. This should be reported as a bug.

Comment: Bug reported to WolframResearch

Comment: @Nasser Can you please use the standard bug header so that the tools for extracting information from bug posts can keep working? https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1610/12

Answer (score 5):

Fyi, Fixed in V 13

```
ListLogPlot[Range[10000], Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Compare to

[image]